# ayuda con un evento datagridview.cellcontenclic

Tags: c#

alguien sabra porque el evento dtgridview se ejecuta mas de una vez? cada vez que cargo un grid, es el numero de veces que se ejecuta este evento
hay alguna forma de controlarlo

## region  Evento de clic en la Imagen

```
    public void DGVMasterGridClickEvents(DataGridView MasterDGV, DataGridView DetailDGV, int columnIndexs, EventTypes eventtype, ControlTypes types,DataTable DetailTable,String FilterColumn)
    {

        MasterDGVs = MasterDGV;
        DetailDGVs = DetailDGV;
        gridColumnIndex = columnIndexs;
        DetailgridDT = DetailTable;
        FilterColumnName = FilterColumn;

       
        MasterDGVs.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(masterDGVs_CellContentClick_Event);


    }
    private void masterDGVs_CellContentClick_Event(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       
        DataGridViewImageColumn cols = (DataGridViewImageColumn)MasterDGVs.Columns[0];
      try { 
       // cols.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
        MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = Image.FromFile("expand.png");

         if (e.ColumnIndex == gridColumnIndex)
         {
            var rutaimagen = ImageName.ToString();
            if (rutaimagen.Length>12) {
                ImageName = Path.GetFileName(ImageName);
            }
                
             if (ImageName == "expand.png")
             {
                 DetailDGVs.Visible = true;
                 ImageName = "toggle.png";
                 // cols.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
                 MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Image.FromFile(ImageName);


                 String Filterexpression = MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[FilterColumnName].Value.ToString();

                 MasterDGVs.Controls.Add(DetailDGVs);
                var filasmaster = MasterDGVs.RowCount;
                var mitadfilas = (filasmaster / 2) + 1;

                 Rectangle dgvRectangle = MasterDGVs.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, e.RowIndex, true);
                 DetailDGVs.Size = new Size(MasterDGVs.Width - 500, 180);
                if (e.RowIndex>=mitadfilas)
                {
                    DetailDGVs.Location = new Point(dgvRectangle.X, dgvRectangle.Y -150);
                }
                else { 
                 DetailDGVs.Location = new Point(dgvRectangle.X, dgvRectangle.Y + 1);
                }

                DataView detailView = new DataView(DetailgridDT);
                 detailView.RowFilter = FilterColumnName + " = '" + Filterexpression + "'";
                 if (detailView.Count <= 0)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("No hay detalles");
                 }
                 DetailDGVs.DataSource = detailView;


             }
             else
             {
                 ImageName = "expand.png";
                 //  cols.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
                 MasterDGVs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
                var rw = e.RowIndex;
                var cl = e.ColumnIndex;
                 DetailDGVs.Visible = false;
             }                 
         }
         else
         {
             DetailDGVs.Visible = false;
             
         }
      }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error"+ex);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: He probado el ejemplo y solo salta el evento cuando selecciono el contenido de la celda. Por lo que debe ser otra parte de tu código la que produce la repetición.

Comment: gracias por responder, te puedo poner todo el codigo haber si ves algo que yo no

Comment: Usas alguna librería no estándar?

Answer (score 0):

```
    #region Variables del Grid
    // Declared for the Master grid
    DataGridView Master_DGV = new DataGridView();
    // Declared for the Detail grid
    DataGridView Detail_DGV = new DataGridView();
    DGVP objdgv = new DGVP();

    List<int> lstNumericTextBoxColumns;


    public int ColumnIndex;
    DataTable dtName = new DataTable();
    #endregion

    #region Eventos del formulario de avance
    clsAvance ava;

    public frmAvanceRuta()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    //va a buscar los detalles del pedido
    private void btnBuscarZona_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ava = new clsAvance();
        string fecha = dtpZona.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        string zona = cmbZonas.SelectedValue.ToString();

        Resultado resZona = ava.pedidosxZona(fecha,zona);


        if (resZona.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {//llenaremos el primer datatable master
            ProgressBar avan = new ProgressBar();
            DataTable dtpedidosZona = new DataTable();
            //agregaremos las columnas que nos traera el datable
            dtpedidosZona.Columns.Add("Zonas del Dia");
            dtpedidosZona.Columns.Add("Avance");

            ///construimos el segundo grid del detalle child
            DataTable dtpedidosZonaDetalle = new DataTable();
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("NoPedido");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("EstatusPedido");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("Zona");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("Almacen");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("FechaPedido", typeof(DateTime));
            //dtpedidosZona.Columns.Add("Lineas");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("NoPaquetes");
            // dtpedidosZona.Columns.Add("IdGuia");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("NoGuia");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("EstatusGuia");
            dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Columns.Add("Avance");
            //
            int sumpaquetes = 0;
            var sumpaquetesauditados=0;
            var porcentaje = 0;
            //
            //llenamos este Grid 
            for (var i = 0; i <= resZona.Datos.Rows.Count-1; i++) {
                var avance = "";
                if (resZona.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() == "3") {
                    avance = "100%";
                    //avan.Value = 100;
                }
                else
                {
                    Resultado calculoporcentaje = ava.pedidosxZonaDetalle(resZona.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                    if (calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (var k = 0; k <= calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; k++)
                        {
                            sumpaquetes = sumpaquetes + Convert.ToInt32( calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows[k].ItemArray[3]);
                            sumpaquetesauditados=sumpaquetesauditados + Convert.ToInt32(calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows[k].ItemArray[4]);
                        }
                        porcentaje = ((sumpaquetesauditados * 100) / sumpaquetes);

                        if(resZona.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() == "2")
                        {
                            avance = Convert.ToString(porcentaje)+"%";
                        }
                        else if (resZona.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() == "2")
                        {
                            avance = Convert.ToString(porcentaje) + "%";
                        }
                    }
                }
                dtpedidosZona.Rows.Add(resZona.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], avance);
                //llenamos el segundo grid manualmente

                string cPedido = resZona.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                Resultado res = ava.pedidosxZona(fecha, zona);
                //Resultado resdetalle = ava.pedidosxZonaDetalle(cPedido);
                if (res.Datos.Rows.Count>0) {
                    for(var j = 0; j <= res.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Rows.Add(res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[0], res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[1],
                            res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[2], res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[3], res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[4],
                             res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[5], res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[6], res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[7]);
                    }

                } else {
                    dtpedidosZonaDetalle.Rows.Add(res.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[0], "No hay Detalle", "No hay detalle", "No hay detalle", "No hay detalle");
                }

            }

            DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
            dsDataSet.Tables.Add(dtpedidosZona);
            dsDataSet.Tables.Add(dtpedidosZonaDetalle);

            DataRelation relacion = new DataRelation("Detalle",dsDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0],dsDataSet.Tables[1].Columns[0],true);
            dsDataSet.Relations.Add(relacion);
            dgvZonas.DataSource = dsDataSet.Tables[0];



        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    //cuando cambia el valor del datetime picker elige todas las zonas de esa fecha
    private void dtpZona_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grpZona.Enabled = true;
        btnBuscarZona.Enabled = true;
        ava = new clsAvance();
        string fecha = dtpZona.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        Resultado Res = ava.selectZona(fecha);
        if (Res.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Res.Datos.Rows.Add("TODAS LAS ZONAS");

            cmbZonas.DataSource = Res.Datos;
            cmbZonas.ValueMember = "Zonas";
            cmbZonas.DisplayMember = "Zonas";
        }
        else
        {
            cmbZonas.DataSource = null;
            cmbZonas.Items.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void dtpRuta_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ava = new clsAvance();
        string fecha = dtpRuta.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        Resultado Res = ava.selectRuta(fecha);
        if (Res.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Res.Datos.Rows.Add(500,"TODAS LAS RUTAS","TODAS LAS RUTAS",2);
            cmbRutas.DataSource = Res.Datos;
            cmbRutas.ValueMember = "Id_Ruta";
            cmbRutas.DisplayMember = "Nombre";

            cmbRutas.SelectedValue = 500;
        }
        else
        {
            cmbRutas.DataSource = null;
            cmbRutas.Items.Clear();
        }
        cmbRutas.Enabled = true;
        btnBuscarRuta.Enabled = true;
        grpRuta.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage current = (sender as TabControl).SelectedTab;
        var nombre = current.Text;
        if (nombre == "Zonas")
        {
            dtpRuta.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2018");

            cmbRutas.DataSource = null;
            cmbRutas.Items.Clear();
            cmbRutas.Enabled = false;
            btnBuscarRuta.Enabled = false;
            grpRuta.Enabled = false;
            pnlGrid.Controls.Clear();
            Master_DGV.DataSource = null;
            Master_DGV.Rows.Clear();
            Master_DGV.Refresh();
            OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind.Clear();
            OrderDetailBindClass.objDetailDGVBind.Clear();
            Detail_DGV.DataSource = null;
            Detail_DGV.Refresh();
            Detail_DGV.Rows.Clear();
            cmbRutas.Enabled = false;
            btnBuscarRuta.Enabled = false;
            grpRuta.Enabled = false;



        }
        else if (nombre=="Rutas")
        {
            grpZona.Enabled = false;
            cmbZonas.DataSource = null;
            cmbZonas.Items.Clear();
            dgvZonas.DataSource = null;
            dgvZonas.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void btnBuscarRuta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // To bind the Master data to List 
        Master_BindData();

        // To bind the Detail data to List 
        Detail_BindData();

        MasterGrid_Initialize();

       // DetailGrid_Initialize();


    }

    #endregion

    #region Metodos del Grid
    private void Master_BindData()
    {

        if (OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind.Count > 0)
        { OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind.Clear(); }
        ProgressBar prueba = new ProgressBar();
        prueba.Value = 100;
        ava = new clsAvance();
        string fecha = dtpRuta.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            Resultado ResRuta = ava.selectRuta(fecha);
        if (ResRuta.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= ResRuta.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var avance = 0;
                var sub = 0;
                var total = "";
                var nPedido = 0;

                ///metodos para hacer el calculo del progressbar
                var idguia = ResRuta.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                Resultado ResPedidos = ava.pedidosxRuta(fecha, idguia);
                nPedido = ResPedidos.Datos.Rows.Count;
                for (var j = 0; j <= ResPedidos.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    var EstatusPedido = ResPedidos.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                    var Pedido= ResPedidos.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                    if (EstatusPedido=="3")
                    {
                        avance = 100;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Resultado calculoporcentaje = ava.pedidosxRutaDetalle(Pedido);
                        if (calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var sumpaquetes = 0;
                            var sumpaquetesauditados = 0;
                            var porcentaje = 0;
                            for (var k = 0; k <= calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; k++)
                            {
                                sumpaquetes = sumpaquetes + Convert.ToInt32(calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows[k].ItemArray[3]);
                                sumpaquetesauditados = sumpaquetesauditados + Convert.ToInt32(calculoporcentaje.Datos.Rows[k].ItemArray[4]);
                            }
                            porcentaje = ((sumpaquetesauditados * 100) / sumpaquetes);

                            if (EstatusPedido == "2")
                            {
                                avance = porcentaje;

                            }
                            else if (EstatusPedido == "2")
                            {
                                avance =porcentaje;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    sub += avance;

                }
                ///
                total = Convert.ToString(sub / nPedido);
                //var pru=avan.Find(x=>x.idguia==idguia);
                ///

                ///metodo para llenar los campos del primer grid y master
                OrderMasterBindClass obj = new OrderMasterBindClass("", ResRuta.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                    ResRuta.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(),total ,dtpRuta.Value);
                OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind.Add(obj);
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }


    }

    private void Detail_BindData()
    {
        ava = new clsAvance();
        if (OrderDetailBindClass.objDetailDGVBind.Count > 0) { OrderDetailBindClass.objDetailDGVBind.Clear(); }
        string fecha = dtpRuta.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        Resultado Res = ava.selectRuta(fecha);
        if (Res.Datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j <= Res.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                var idguia = Res.Datos.Rows[j].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                Resultado ResRutaDetalle = ava.pedidosxRuta(fecha,idguia);
                for (var i = 0; i <= ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var fec =Convert.ToDateTime( ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);

                    OrderDetailBindClass obj = new OrderDetailBindClass(ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                        ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(), ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString(),
                       fec, ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString(),
                       ResRutaDetalle.Datos.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString());
                    OrderDetailBindClass.objDetailDGVBind.Add(obj);
                }
            }




        }
        else
        {

        }




    }

    // to generate Master Datagridview with your coding
    public void MasterGrid_Initialize()
    {

        if (Master_DGV.RowCount > 0 | Master_DGV.ColumnCount>0) {
            Master_DGV.DataSource = null;
            Master_DGV.Rows.Clear(); 
            Master_DGV.Columns.Clear();
            Master_DGV.Refresh();

        }
        //First generate the grid Layout Design
        DGVP.Layouts(Master_DGV, Color.LightSteelBlue, Color.AliceBlue, Color.WhiteSmoke, false, Color.SteelBlue, false, false, false);

        //Set Height,width and add panel to your selected control
        DGVP.Generategrid(Master_DGV, pnlGrid, 1320, 470, 10, 10);

        pnlGrid.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
        // Color Image Column creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Master_DGV, ControlTypes.ImageColumn, "img", " ", " ", true, 26, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Transparent);

        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Master_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "Nombre", "Ruta", "Ruta", true, 90, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);

        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Master_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "Descripcion", "Descripcion", "Descripcion", true, 270, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Master_DGV, ControlTypes.ProgressBar, "Avance", "Avance", "Avance", true, 250, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Green, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Master_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "FechaGuia", "FechaGuia", "FechaGuia", true, 140, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        //Convert the List to DataTable
        DataTable detailTableList = ListtoDataTable(OrderDetailBindClass.objDetailDGVBind);

        // Image Colum Click Event - In  this method we create an event for cell click and we will display the Detail grid with result.

        objdgv.DGVMasterGridClickEvents(Master_DGV, Detail_DGV, Master_DGV.Columns["img"].Index, EventTypes.cellContentClick, ControlTypes.ImageColumn, detailTableList, "Nombre");

        // Bind data to DGV.//filtrado de lista para el cambio del combo box
        if (cmbRutas.Text=="TODAS LAS RUTAS")
        {
            Master_DGV.DataSource = OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind;
        }
        else
        {
            var valor = cmbRutas.Text;
            OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind = OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind.Where(x => x.Nombre == valor).ToList();
            Master_DGV.DataSource = OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind;
        }
        ///////////////////////////ahora inicializacion
        if (Detail_DGV.ColumnCount > 0 | Detail_DGV.RowCount > 0)
        {
            Detail_DGV.DataSource = null;
            Detail_DGV.Rows.Clear();
            Detail_DGV.Columns.Clear();
            Detail_DGV.Refresh();
        }
        //First generate the grid Layout Design
        DGVP.Layouts(Detail_DGV, Color.Peru, Color.Wheat, Color.Tan, false, Color.Sienna, false, false, false);

        //Set Height,width and add panel to your selected control
        DGVP.Generategrid(Detail_DGV, pnlGrid, 300, 200, 10, 10);

        // Color Dialog Column creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "Nombre", "Ruta", "Ruta", true, 90, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);

        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "NoPedido", "NoPedido", "NoPedido", true, 80, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);

        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "EstatusPedido", "EstatusPedido", "EstatusPedido", true, 80, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "FechaPedido", "FechaPedido", "FechaPedido", true, 200, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "GuiaNumero", "GuiaNumero", "GuiaNumero", true, 100, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "GuiaEstatus", "GuiaEstatus", "GuiaEstatus", true, 120, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);

        // objdgv.DGVDetailGridClickEvents(Detail_DGV);

    }
    //List to Data Table Convert
    private static DataTable ListtoDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> DetailList)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var typeproperties = type.GetProperties();

        DataTable listToDT = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in typeproperties)
        {
            listToDT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(propInfo.Name, propInfo.PropertyType));
        }

        foreach (T ListItem in DetailList)
        {
            object[] values = new object[typeproperties.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < typeproperties.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = typeproperties[i].GetValue(ListItem, null);
            }

            listToDT.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return listToDT;
    }


    // to generate Detail Datagridview with your coding
   /* public void DetailGrid_Initialize()
    {
        if (Detail_DGV.ColumnCount > 0|Detail_DGV.RowCount>0)
        {
            Detail_DGV.DataSource = null;
            Detail_DGV.Rows.Clear();
            Detail_DGV.Columns.Clear();
            Detail_DGV.Refresh();
        }
        //First generate the grid Layout Design
        DGVP.Layouts(Detail_DGV, Color.Peru, Color.Wheat, Color.Tan, false, Color.Sienna, false, false, false);

        //Set Height,width and add panel to your selected control
        DGVP.Generategrid(Detail_DGV, pnlGrid, 300, 200, 10, 10);

        // Color Dialog Column creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "Nombre", "Ruta", "Ruta", true, 90, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);

        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "NoPedido", "NoPedido", "NoPedido", true, 80, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);

        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "EstatusPedido", "EstatusPedido", "EstatusPedido", true, 80, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "FechaPedido", "FechaPedido", "FechaPedido", true, 200, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV, ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "GuiaNumero", "GuiaNumero", "GuiaNumero", true, 100, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


        // BoundColumn creation
        DGVP.Templatecolumn(Detail_DGV,ControlTypes.BoundColumn, "GuiaEstatus", "GuiaEstatus", "GuiaEstatus", true, 120, DataGridViewTriState.True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Color.Transparent, null, "", "", Color.Black);


       // objdgv.DGVDetailGridClickEvents(Detail_DGV);


    }*/
    #endregion
}
```

}